# How to convert a number in Python to 8 binary bytes (64-bit long)?

Tags: python, python-2.x

How do I convert a number in Python to 8 binary bytes (64-bit long)?

I have a blueprint of a network message, part of which is a number represented with eight bytes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [struct.pack](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-strings):

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('!Q', 123)
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00{'
```

The first argument is a [format string](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-strings) which controls the encoding. `!` means network byte order and `Q` is for 8-byte unsigned integers.